# Tasker/Security Settings 2G switch not working on OnePlus X CM13

Tags: cyanogenmod, tasker, gsm, 2g, oneplus-x

I'm stuck with my planned automatization with tasker and security settings. My idea is to automatically switch to 2G/GSM when I connect to a WLAN. When disconnecting I want to switch back to 3G/4G.

I'm on Sultans CM13 on my OPX (rooted). What i did so far: Installed tasker and security settings (SS) and configured a tasker profile with a task using the SS plugin (based on [this XDA tutorial](http://forum.xda-developers.com/u/tasker-tips-tricks/guide-switch-to-2g-connected-to-wifi-t3330876)).

Under Actions --> Device Setting I picked *global* as table and set the value of *preferred_network_mode1* to 1 (I also tested 0). I also configured the shell script described in the tutorial. But my phone is not switching to 2G when activating the WLAN although the profile is active. #edit: I just saw that there is also a parameter called preferred_network_mode followed by a 10 digit number, but it is not working either. No switch to 2G or from 2G to 3G.

Now I wanted to check if my phone/provider has another value perhaps, but when I'm executing:

`sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db
SELECT name, value FROM global;`

as `su` I get the message that the table `global` is not existing. Does anyone has an idea how I can access this database or how to configure Tasker/Security Settings on my OnePlus X (with CM13) in Germany (T-Mobile)?

Comment: This might help: [Simple way to toggle between 2G and 3G connection](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/82379) // BTW, that command of yours didn't work because Marshmallow did away with relying on *settings.db*. You need to use `settings` command. Related: [Where is the database to save android volumes](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/139840)

Comment: Thank you for the second hint. Concerning the first one: I wanted to solve it with Tasker/SecuritySettings and not with Xposed and Gravity. I already found this...but if there is no other solution I will have to switch.

Comment: I can't find the `preferred_network_mode` (or anything similar) in the xml file so I have to look in this folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is the way I solved it: After discovering the right place to edit the preferred network mode I tested to change it:

```
adb shell settings put global preferred_network_mode 1
adb shell settings put global preferred_network_mode1 1
adb shell settings put global preferred_network_mode2456921 1
adb shell stop ril-daemon
adb shell start ril-daemon
```

The problem was that the changes were not reflected and with the restart of the ril-daemon they were reset (`preferred_network_mode 9`).

So I used Gravity Box (Xposed module) to change it and with this it's working fine:

```
Send Intent [
Action: gravitybox.intent.action.CHANGE_NETWORK_TYPE
Extra: networkType:1
]
```

Sadly it was not working without it (so I could have saved the money for Security Settings but however.

So if you want to try it with tasker I would recommend to use it with Xposed and Gravity - that's probably the easiest way actually.